# How can use crypto js publicEncrypt and privateDecrypt in client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cryptojs

I'm using `nodejs` api `Crypto` for generate public and private key. And encrypt and decrypt messages using those key. Everything is fine in server side. But how can I use `crypto.publicEncrypt()` in client side?

Answer (score -2):

You can download the javascript file from [**HERE**](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) and then add it in the client side like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to/bower_components/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES(...);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.SHA256(...);
</script>
```